# Ignore files with GetFiles

Tags: c#, vb.net

How can I switch this function so that instead of finding bad files it ignores them..
what I have currently is not ignoring..

```
Dim files As System.IO.FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles.Where(Function(fi) fi.Extension.ToLower <> ".bad1" Or fi.Extension.ToLower <> ".bad2" Or fi.Extension.ToLower <> ".bad3").ToArray
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim files As System.IO.FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles().Where(Function(fi) Not (fi.Extension.ToLower() = ".bad1" OrElse fi.Extension.ToLower() = ".bad2" OrElse fi.Extension.ToLower() = ".bad3")).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `Not Equal` + `OR`.

Change the `OR` to `AND` and it will exclude.

```
Dim files As System.IO.FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles.Where(Function(fi) fi.Extension.ToLower <> ".bad1" AND fi.Extension.ToLower <> ".bad2" AND fi.Extension.ToLower <> ".bad3").ToArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `AND` instead of `OR` because you are trying to ignore ALL bad files, like:

```
Dim files As System.IO.FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles().Where(Function(fi) fi.Extension.ToLower <> ".bad1" And fi.Extension.ToLower <> ".bad2" And fi.Extension.ToLower <> ".bad3").ToArray
```

By the way `fi` parameter on this context has no `Extension` property, so why not use
`Path.GetExtension()` under `System.IO` namespace, like:

```
Dim files As System.IO.FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles().Where(Function(fi) Path.GetExtension(fi) <> ".bad1" And Path.GetExtension(fi) <> ".bad2" And Path.GetExtension(fi) <> ".bad3").ToArray
```